# Is there a way to get the size of Outlook Calendar meeting items?

Tags: windows-xp, calendar, microsoft-outlook-2003

In our Exchange environment, our company caps the size of an Exchange account at a certain size.  That size is the sum of all the exchange related stuff stored on the server - includign both the Inbox and the Calendar.

I can tell with the Mailbox properties, Folder Size... window that my Calendar is a good 50% of my account's footprint.

Is there any way to get a more detailed view of what meetings in the Calendar are taking up the space?  Given the general pattern of incoming mail, it's my belief that 2-5 meetings are responsible for 75% of the memory consumption... I just need to find *which* meetings are the problem... and with my current calendar, it's a bit like finding a needle in a haystack.

Anyone got a trick for this?

Other details - it's Outlook 2003 on XP

Answer (score 1):

- Open up your calendar
- Switch to the **All Appointments** view
- Right click on one of the column titles and select **Field Chooser**
- Select **All Appointment Fields** from the dropdown
- Drag The **Size** field next to one of the existing columns
- Close the Field Chooser
- Click on the Size column to sort by size.

Comment: How do I get to the "All Appointments" view? My inclination was the View menu, but that isn't right...  FYI - I'm using 2003

Comment: @bethlakshmi - You can use "By Category" view for this